# Incorrect subscription when using two delegates with single event

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Hello guys I'm getting some troubles using delegates to subscript to same event trought two forms (parent and child), this is my code :

```
public delegate void SplitDelegate(object s, ControllerEventArgs e);
public delegate void SetBatchDelegate(object s, ControllerEventArgs e);

public class ControllerEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string sp1;
    public int ip1;
    public int ip2;

    public ControllerEventArgs(string sp1)
    {
        this.sp1 = sp1;
    }

    public ControllerEventArgs(int p1, int p2)
    {
        this.ip1 = p1;
        this.ip2 = p2;
    }

    public ControllerEventArgs(string sp1, int p1, int p2)
    {
        this.sp1 = sp1;
        this.ip1 = p1;
        this.ip2 = p2;
    }
}

public interface IController
{
    event SplitDelegate splitRowEvent;
    event SetBatchDelegate setSmallBatchEvent;
    void InvokeControllerEvent(string p1);
    void InvokeControllerEvent(int p1, int p2);
    void InvokeControllerEvent(string sp1, int p1, int p2);

}

public class Controller : IController
{
    public event SplitDelegate splitRowEvent;
    public event SetBatchDelegate setSmallBatchEvent;

    public void InvokeControllerEvent(string p1)
    {
        this.OnControllerEvent(new ControllerEventArgs(p1));
    }

    public void InvokeControllerEvent(int p1, int p2)
    {
        this.OnControllerEvent(new ControllerEventArgs(p1, p2));
    }

    public void InvokeControllerEvent(string sp1, int p1, int p2)
    {
        this.OnControllerEvent(new ControllerEventArgs(sp1, p1, p2));
    }

    protected virtual void OnControllerEvent(ControllerEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.splitRowEvent != null)
        {
            this.splitRowEvent.Invoke(this.splitRowEvent, e);
        }
        if (this.setSmallBatchEvent != null)
        {
            this.setSmallBatchEvent.Invoke(this.setSmallBatchEvent, e);
        }
    }
}
```

For example, when I call in Form A :

```
frmFormB.controller.InvokeControllerEvent("ugPER");
```

Both invokations are processed when I just want to use the first one `SplitRowEvent`

Is there a way to remake my code using the correct syntax for get the correct callback?

Added for best explanation :

button1_click :

```
SmallBatchSplitSetRows frmModal = new SmallBatchSplitSetRows(this.controller);
            frmModal.controller.InvokeControllerEvent("ugFAB");
            frmModal.ShowDialog();
```

button2_click :

```
 SmallBatchSplitInput frmModal = new SmallBatchSplitInput(this.controller);
            frmModal.controller.InvokeControllerEvent("ugPER");
            frmModal.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `OnControllerEvent` method *explicitly* calls uses `splitRowEvent` and `setSmallBatchEvent`. If you don't want it to, just change the contents of the method.

Ultimately it's not clear why you've got two different events but only one way of invoking them, via three overloads. Are the three overloads meant to do different things? Is each one meant to call a different set of event handlers? This is where using descriptive names instead of overloading would be really helpful.

Comment: Hi @Jon, yes the 3 overloads provides 3 diferents ways to pass parameters between forms, when I remove the explicitly use of each event I get the samething

Comment: @AngelEscobedo: But why do you have two events in the first place, and how are you expecting to determine which event to raise when?

Comment: How the controller will know which one have to invoke and not the other one? a code snippet will be very helpfully, thanks

Comment: Because there are two events in my parent form that need to be differentiated, Im raising each one in differents button clicks events

Comment: @AngelEscobedo: No, you've missed the point - *you* need to say under which circumstances it should raise which event. You've declared two events, and you've got one method which raises both events. You need to think about *why* you've got two events, and *when* you want to raise each of them. I can't possibly do that for you - it's *your* design.

Comment: Okay, so you've got two events in your parent form. Fine - now why are you raising them both in `OnControllerEvent`?

Comment: I don't know the syntax to select which event have to be raised, that's the true, It was working with one single event..

Comment: @AngelEscobedo: It's not a matter of syntax - look at your OnControllerEvent method: it's got two sections, one to deal with `setSmallBatchEvent` and one to do with `splitRowEvent`. Do you see them both? Do you understand why both events are firing? Now when you call `OnControllerEvent`, *which event do you want to be raised*? Simply get rid of the code that raises the other one.

Comment: I think I got it, wait a minutes please